# Pass SetState from parent component to a child component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In React js I would pass setState like below from parent components to child components, however in React Native setABC is undefined. What's the best way to achieve the below in React Native?

Parent.js:

```
function Parent(){


    const [ABC, setABC] = useState();



     return(
        <routes>
           <route path="/child" element={<Child setABC={setABC} />} />
        </routes>
     );

}


export default Parent;
```

Child.js:

```
function Child({setABC}){

    let doSomeStuff = () =>{

        setABC("ABC");

    }

 }

 export default Child;
```

Comment: The name of attribute on Child is setState, not setABC

Answer (score 1):

the problem is not related to react-native
you passed the prop as `setState` in parent.js

```
<Child setState={setABC} />
```

and received it as `setABC` `function Child({setABC}){`

it should be like this

```
function Child({setState}) {
...
}
```

or change the prop name in `Parent.js` to match `Chlid.js`

```
<route path="/child" element={<Child setABC={setABC} />} />
```